# How does the 45 degree banking rule apply when plotting multiple data series in one chart?

Tags: data-visualization

Cleveland's rule of thumb that the average slope of a line should be 45 degrees. But what about when a chart plots multiple data series? Is there a generalization of Cleveland's rule, or do you set the chart's aspect ratio by the "Eh, that looks good" method?

Comment: Bill Cleveland did spectacularly good work on graphics, but this rule of thumb long predates him. It's in Fisher's _Statistical methods for research workers_, in essence, to name only one antecedent. But it was always about the typical slope, and that principle just extends when there are several variables as well as several up- or down- segments in a single series.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Visweek 2012 paper, *An Empirical Model of Slope Ratio Comparisons* [[PDF]](http://vis.stanford.edu/files/2012-SlopeComparison-InfoVis.pdf) by
Justin Talbot, John Gerth, and Pat Hanrahan, attempts to generalize the question of optimal banking. Excerpt from introduction:

> Despite the practical success of this guideline, its perceptual underpinnings
>   remain unclear. Cleveland et al. justified the guideline with
>   an experiment that showed that placing the mid-angle of two lines (the
>   angle halfway between them) at 45° minimizes errors made in judging
>   the ratio of their slopes. However, examination of their experimental
>   design suggests that this conclusion might not be generally applicable.
>   ...
>   This paper seeks to improve our understanding of slope ratio estimation
>   in line plots through empirical modeling and experimentation.

The experiments suggest the optimal median angle may be around 30° and that flatter is better for perceiving angle differences. Excerpt of a graph supporting the former point (observed error in black; predicted error in red):

[image]

However, like seemingly every other research paper, the bottom line is:

> It is still unclear if the results derived in our studies for pairwise discrete comparisons will transfer to real plots. ...
>   there remains substantial work to be done to
>   build a solid understanding of aspect ratio selection.

Related papers:

- *Arc Length-Based Aspect Ratio Selection* [[PDF]](http://vis.stanford.edu/files/2011-ArclengthBanking-InfoVis.pdf), Justin Talbot, John Gerth, and Pat Hanrahan
- *Crowdsourcing Graphical Perception: Using Mechanical Turk to Assess Visualization Design* [[PDF]](http://vis.stanford.edu/files/2010-MTurk-CHI.pdf), Jeffrey Heer and Michael Bostock

Comment: Nice answer! Another similar paper on testing Cleveland's perceptual hierarchy is Heer and Bostock http://vis.stanford.edu/files/2010-MTurk-CHI.pdf. For time series it is important to plot on several different aspect ratios, to see long term trend vs seasonal trend. For multivariate data scatterplots should have a square aspect ratio to perceive association better. Show your data on several different aspect ratios in your plots, like you would use several different binwidths when making histograms.

Comment: Thanks Di, I added a link to that paper and another I found. I like your other points. You might expand them into a separate answer or appended them to this answer.